# What are the critera that exclude those question from search?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, search

I was looking at the top downvoted question using the [voted tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) and going to the last result.

But the result didn't match what I was expecting, only the one with status ok was in the result.

```
Status  score                   title                                                            link
        -154   Forcing a function to return if false                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068763    
        -147   How to send 100,000 emails weekly?                                           https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734    
        -116   Finding the maximum value of an array                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544387    
OK      -75    Javascript performance, conditional statement vs assignment operator         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17686749    
        -73    Single layer neural network                                                  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455660    
        -65    What is System.currentTimeMillis()?                                          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20057935    
        -65    How to find all the indexes of all the occurrences of a word in a string     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185374    
        -61    Edit page source code with JavaScript                                        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22881919    
OK      -55    How do I remove a style element from an inline style using regex?            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791292    
OK      -52    Return Json object with Duplicate Keys using C#                              https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42384565    
        -51    How to show Snackbar at top of the screen                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746300    
        -50    Why does i|= j|= k|= (j+= i) - - (k+++k) - - (i =+j) == 11?                  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519990    
OK      -50    How to collate attribute values stored as dicts within a list?               https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25970488    
        -48    How is assignment made in this expression?                                   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172777    
        -47    Why does Swing get error with parseInt()?                                    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972289
```

Tag and Filter option:

- Filter = All
- Tag = None

#### Page Check:

Result are incorrect on :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes
But are correct on :
https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=936259&tab=Votes&q=is%3aquestion

#### Login check:

When not logged :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes
-> Give SO Custom 404, Page Not Found , No Results

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes
-> Works both logged and not logged , Good Results

#### The Not So Real Page: Only if you Opt in for "new question filter"

Some of you seems to get the 404 on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes), Here is a step by step way to get it. [image]

Here some proof:
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've changed your link as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes` comes back as a 404 for me. What do you mean _only the one with status ok was in the result_? Do you have any other search criteria that is interfering with the result?

Comment: This is not consistent.  Pagination has always been broken to some degree, doing so while questions are constantly added and deleted and keeping it performant while you are browsing the pages is not easy.  There was an early blog/podcast about it from the site founders, can't find it back.  Nobody really worries about this.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you only saying you see 4 results? If so - where are you getting the others  from? All appears fine going to the last page of https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes or doing a search for `is:q score:-200..-45`

Comment: @JonClements, Expected data stack echange. No filter, tag or keyword are used. Only sorting question by vote and going to last page

Comment: Added information to the question, Result are incorrect using the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes pages, Do you need a Big screen shoot to prove my claims?

Comment: @DragandDrop would be interesting to know how you keep insisting how the results are wrong on a page that doesn't exist... Have you looked at the last page of https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes ?

Comment: @JonClements, Just update this point in my question! ;)

Comment: So you're not getting the results you expect on a page that doesn't exist, but on the ones that do, it's fine? What exactly is the problem then?

Comment: @JonClements, 
What is the correct way to prove that page existe? Is a dumb of Http request and answer ok ? screen shoot enhought ?

Comment: Sure - show me that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/votes exists...

Comment: @DragandDrop ahh... okay - you need to have the "new question filter" enabled in your preferences for that (which is off by default). That's more designed towards looking for new/recent questions/posts of interest than older posts (which the highest negatively scored posts will generally be). Try fiddling with the page size before going to the last page and see if that may work.

Comment: @JonClements, Changing the Page size on the site does not change the result, updating fiddler but the results seems to be the same.

Comment: So now it's a bug report I will format the question when I have more time.

Comment: @DragandDrop Now I can see that page! Thanks for adding the extra detail in your post. It seems as if it's adding the `closed:no` flag by default.

Comment: @George, I'm not crazy, OK! I see things that looks real! They are real.. At least for me! Now you are seeing things too.. I'm sorry.. It was in my head.. Don't make them real! We need to stop talking about it..